# How to get the exact, full version number of Perl that's installed?

Tags: perl, version

I know I've got Perl 5.20.1.1 installed.  But can I determine that programmatically?

`$]` only gives the revision, version and sub-version, i.e. `5.020001` for me, meaning `5.20.1`.

The `Config` module (documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html)) doesn't *seem* to give anything deeper than that.  For me:

```
perl -MConfig -e 'foreach (sort keys %Config) { print "$_ -> $Config{$_}\n" if /version|revision/io; }'
```

gives:

```
PERL_API_REVISION -> 5
PERL_API_SUBVERSION -> 0
PERL_API_VERSION -> 20
PERL_REVISION -> 5
PERL_SUBVERSION -> 1
PERL_VERSION -> 20
Revision -> $Revision
SUBVERSION -> 1
api_revision -> 5
api_subversion -> 0
api_version -> 20
api_versionstring -> 5.20.0
ccversion ->
d_inc_version_list ->
d_libm_lib_version ->
db_version_major -> 0
db_version_minor -> 0
db_version_patch -> 0
gccversion -> 4.8.3
gnulibc_version ->
ignore_versioned_solibs ->
inc_version_list ->
inc_version_list_init -> 0
revision -> 5
subversion -> 1
version -> 5.20.1
version_patchlevel_string -> version 20 subversion 1
versiononly ->
```

I don't *think* there's anything in there that gives any more information, but it probably doesn't help that in my case the sub-version number is the same as the sub-sub-version number!

Is there anywhere else I can look?  Or have I perhaps missed something in `%Config`?

Answer (score 5):

Official Perl releases only have three parts. "5" is the language, "20" is the major version and "1" is the minor version. Anything more than that was added by someone else (at a guess, whoever packaged the Perl you're using), so you probably will not find it from inside Perl.